# <input type="file" restarts Ionic app after choosing file

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I have a file input:

```
<input #fileInput class="task-uploader__input" type="file" multiple />
```

I am able to bring up the file chooser (camera or gallery), and when I choose a photo, the app restarts.  I'm not sure if it is crashing, or if it is just restarting, but this is not the behavior I want in my application after choosing a photo.

It even crashes if I choose a very small photo, so I don't think its memory related.  Why is this occurring?

Comment: Hey ! Did you find a solution about this ? Some Android devices as the same problem with my app...

Comment: I also have this issue, on Android. It does not always happen but sometimes. It seems to happen only on Xiaomi device. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions issue. You need to add permission usage description to your project so you can access and use gallery & camera properly on IOS.

In config.xml, under `<platform name="ios">` add the following lines to insert the required permissions to the info.plist file.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>A message that tells the user why the app is requesting access to the device’s camera.</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>A message that tells the user why the app is requesting access to the user’s photo library.</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
    <string>A message that tells the user why the app is requesting write-only access to the user’s photo library.</string>
</edit-config>
```

Then save config.xml, run `$ ionic cordova prepare ios`, clean xcode project and build again.

Note: I've added each permission's description between `<string>` tags so you understand them, but you need to replace them with custom usage description of how you use each of them in your app to be able to publish it on App Store later.

To do further readings about IOS permissions and get a list of them [check this URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list)

Comment: it was not permisssions